# Upscaled PPM image (no filtering)

Tags: c++, winforms, command-line-interface

The problem I have is that my PPM image is too small, and when I want to show it in the window (there is no scalling,zooming available, and I must save the image on the disk) , I just use an easy function to upscale the pixels (or rather just write it more times into the file). But after this, the image just turns out to be really messy (as seen on screenshot) and with wrong resolution. I've tried many things through last 4 hours but nothing will work.
Is there any solution to this or am I just missing something obvious or doing just many things wrong?
I'm using PictureBox in C++ cli Windows Forms (VS) but the same shows in image viewers (WinExplorer, IrfanView).

Heres the main code, size is the dimension (the image is a square), color just indicates if it wants to be color, and pixelsize enlarges the pixels.
Also I provide full git code [Here](https://github.com/OsaPL/ojp2_cli)

```
int sizemult = size; 
        if (color)
            sizemult *= 3; //3 values of RGB

        std::fstream file;
        file.open("temp.ppm", std::ios::trunc | std::ios::out);
        if (color)
            file << "P3" << std::endl;
        else
            file << "P2" << std::endl;
        file << size*pixelsize << " " << size*pixelsize << std::endl;
        file << 256 << std::endl;

        for (auto i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (auto h = 0; h < pixelsize; h++) {
                for (auto k = 0; k < size*sizemult; k++) {
                    for (auto j = 0; j < pixelsize; j++) {
                        file << table[i*size+k] << " ";
                    }
                }
                file << std::endl;
            }
        }


        file.close();

}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoGik.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my problem was in the for loops. Here is the corrected code, with added color compatibility.

```
int sizemult = size;
        if (color)
            sizemult *= 3;

        std::default_random_engine e1(r());
        std::uniform_real_distribution <double> dist(0, 256);
        table = (double*)calloc(size*sizemult, sizeof(double));
        for (auto j = 0; j < size*sizemult  ; j++) {
            table[j] = dist(e1);
            //table[j] = rand() % 256;
        }

        std::fstream file;
        file.open("temp.ppm", std::ios::trunc | std::ios::out);
        if (color)
            file << "P3" << std::endl;
        else
            file << "P2" << std::endl;
        file << size*pixelsize << " " << size*pixelsize << std::endl;
        file << 256 << std::endl;

        for (auto i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (auto h = 0; h < pixelsize; h++) {
                for (auto k = 0; k < sizemult; k++) {
                    for (auto j = 0; j < pixelsize; j++) {
                        if (color) {
                            file << (int)table[i*size + k] << " ";
                            file << (int)table[i*size + k+1] << " ";
                            file << (int)table[i*size + k+2] << " ";
                        }
                        else
                            file << (int)table[i*size+k] << " ";
                    }
                    if (color)
                        k += 2;
                }
                file << std::endl;
            }
        }
```